# How can I show that if two equal sums have the same coefficients, their terms must be equal?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $k_n$ is a sequence with elements either 1 or 0. Also we define $l_n$ to be a sequence with elements either 1 or 0.

Now suppose I have me following relationship:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}
k_n 2^{-n} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} l_n 2^{-n}$.

Logically I know that $l_n$=$k_n$ for all n but don't know how to prove this. Could it be something regarding a base 2 representation? Thank you!

Comment: Well, you have $$2^{-1} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^{-n},$$ so $k_1 = 1$, and $k_n = 0$ for $n > 1$, and $l_n = 1-k_n$ for all $n$ are two different coefficient sequences with the same sum.

Comment: I would just consider base 2 as you suggested. This is pretty much like asking "if two numbers are the same do they have the same decimal representation?"